# Syntax Error unexpected identifier for bcrypt function. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, bcrypt

Developing a login authenticator using node, express, mysql, brcpt etc. I got stuck here when the `bcrypt.compare` is giving a syntax error in the console which I am unable to debug.

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
        const email = req.body.email
        const password = req.body.password
        if (email && password) {
        con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?", [email, password], function(err, results, fields){
            if (await bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword, (err, isMatch) => {
                if (err) throw err
                callback(null, isMatch)
            }) && results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true
                request.session.email = email
                response.redirect('/')
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!')
            }           
            response.end()
        })
        } else {
            response.send('Please enter Username and Password!')
            response.end()
        }
    })
```

Given above is the login handle and route for the process.

Here is the error thrown out to the terminal:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/server.js:51
            if (await bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword, (err, isMatch) => {
                      ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1067:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1115:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Please help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `app.post` callback is `async`, but your `con.query` callback *isn't*. If whatever is providing `con.query` supports a promise-based interface, use that so you can `await` it.

Comment: How does on do that? I just picked up node.js and I know nothing of what you've just spoken. Please explain.

Comment: Then I'd recommend starting with a structured JavaScript tutorial to understand the basic syntax of what's happening. Then read up on promises generally, followed by async/await specifically. Look for "promise" in your library docs and see their examples.

Comment: Would you suggest using a ```try``` ```catch``` block here?

Comment: You have a *syntax* problem, you can't fix that with try and catch. That's why I suggest starting with fundamentals of the language you're trying to use.